# How to add date time picker in shopify section setting

Tags: datepicker, shopify, jquery-ui-datepicker

How could I add date time picker option in `Shopify -> Store -> Customize -> Section Setting`.

I want to add sliders to be displayed on scheduled basis. So created option there to enter the date time field. Now I wanted the datepicker should be visible when I click on that field, as usually it is done on the text boxes.

I tried to add a `jQuery datepicker` on the section. but it always shows as datepicker is undefined.

Answer (score 5):

Added next fields to setting for same task. Very pity but liquid can't insert variable to schema((

```
    {
      "type": "header",
      "content": "Start date"
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "start_year",
      "label": "Year",
        "min": 2019,
        "max": 2023,
        "step": 1,
      "default": 2019
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "start_month",
      "label": "Month",
        "min": 1,
        "max": 12,
        "step": 1,
      "default": 11
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "start_day",
      "label": "Day",
        "min": 1,
        "max": 31,
        "step": 1,
      "default": 27
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "start_hours",
      "label": "Hours",
        "min": 0,
        "max": 23,
        "step": 1,
      "default": 16
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "start_minute",
      "label": "Minute",
        "min": 0,
        "max": 60,
        "step": 1,
      "default": 0
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no date picker in Shopify but you can get the date from settings like this way: ( place the code in you schema settings )

```
       {
            "type": "text",
            "id": "date_picker",
            "label": "Choose date",
            "default": "12-24-2022",
            "info": "e.g. mm-dd-yyyy"
        }
```

And then just add or assign the date with a filter and I think you will get exactly what you wanted without the visual date picker like **jQuery date picker**

`{{ section.settings.date_picker | date: "%m-%d-%Y" }}`

Hope, this will help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no datepicker field in Shopify.

You will need to use a standard text field and use it as a date base.

Please refer to the docs for the available fields:

[Basic Input Settings](https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/settings/input-settings#basic-input-settings)

[Specialized input settings](https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/settings/input-settings#specialized-input-settings)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular text field in the format `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` to enter the end date and time in your schema, like in the example below:

```
{
  "type": "text",
  "id": "end_time",
  "label": "End date and time",
  "default": "30/05/2023 23:00:00",
  "info": "Format: dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
}
```

Then, you can convert this string into a date object in your .liquid file using the `date` filter and specifying the correct format:

```
{% assign end_date = section.settings.end_time | date: "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S" %}
```

This will create a date object that can be used in time calculations or formatted as needed.

To display the date in a specific format, such as `30 May 2023 23:00:00 GMT+01:00`, you can use the `date` filter again to format the date as desired:

```
{{ end_date | date: "%-d %B %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%:z" }}
```

Where `%B` is the full name of the month, `%z` is the timezone offset, and `%:z` displays the timezone offset with a colon between the hours and minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would add to this answer since I just had to create a new method. I used to use a single line method but that can cause errors (since content authors aren't the brightest and will format the date/time incorrectly) Instead I made a series of dropdowns:

```
      {
        "type": "header",
        "content": "Start date"
      },
      {
        "type": "select",
        "id": "start_year",
        "label": "Year",
        "options": [
          {
            "value": "2023",
            "label": "2023"
          },
          {
            "value": "2024",
            "label": "2024"
          },
          {
            "value": "2025",
            "label": "2025"
          },
          {
            "value": "2026",
            "label": "2026"
          },
          {
            "value": "2027",
            "label": "2027"
          },
          {
            "value": "2028",
            "label": "2028"
          },
          {
            "value": "2029",
            "label": "2029"
          },
          {
            "value": "2030",
            "label": "2030"
          },
          {
            "value": "2031",
            "label": "2031"
          },
          {
            "value": "2032",
            "label": "2032"
          },
          {
            "value": "2033",
            "label": "2033"
          },
          {
            "value": "2034",
            "label": "2034"
          },
          {
            "value": "2035",
            "label": "2035"
          },
          {
            "value": "2036",
            "label": "2036"
          },
          {
            "value": "2037",
            "label": "2037"
          },
          {
            "value": "2038",
            "label": "2038"
          },
          {
            "value": "2039",
            "label": "2039"
          },
          {
            "value": "2040",
            "label": "2040"
          }
        ],
        "default": "2023"
      },
      {
        "type": "select",
        "id": "start_month",
        "label": "Month",
        "options": [
          {
            "value": "1",
            "label": "January"
          },
          {
            "value": "2",
            "label": "February"
          },
          {
            "value": "3",
            "label": "March"
          },
              {
            "value": "4",
            "label": "April"
          },
          {
            "value": "5",
            "label": "May"
          },
          {
            "value": "6",
            "label": "June"
          },
              {
            "value": "7",
            "label": "July"
          },
          {
            "value": "8",
            "label": "August"
          },
          {
            "value": "9",
            "label": "September"
          },
              {
            "value": "10",
            "label": "October"
          },
          {
            "value": "11",
            "label": "November"
          },
          {
            "value": "12",
            "label": "December"
          }
        ],
        "default": "1"
      },
      {
        "type": "select",
        "id": "start_day",
        "label": "Day",
        "options": [
          {
            "value": "1",
            "label": "1"
          },
          {
            "value": "2",
            "label": "2"
          },
          {
            "value": "3",
            "label": "3"
          },
              {
            "value": "4",
            "label": "4"
          },
          {
            "value": "5",
            "label": "5"
          },
          {
            "value": "6",
            "label": "6"
          },
              {
            "value": "7",
            "label": "7"
          },
          {
            "value": "8",
            "label": "8"
          },
          {
            "value": "9",
            "label": "9"
          },
              {
            "value": "10",
            "label": "10"
          },
          {
            "value": "11",
            "label": "11"
          },
          {
            "value": "12",
            "label": "12"
          },
              {
            "value": "13",
            "label": "13"
          },
          {
            "value": "14",
            "label": "14"
          },
          {
            "value": "15",
            "label": "15"
          },
              {
            "value": "16",
            "label": "16"
          },
          {
            "value": "17",
            "label": "17"
          },
          {
            "value": "18",
            "label": "18"
          },
              {
            "value": "19",
            "label": "19"
          },
          {
            "value": "20",
            "label": "20"
          },
          {
            "value": "21",
            "label": "21"
          },
              {
            "value": "22",
            "label": "22"
          },
          {
            "value": "23",
            "label": "23"
          },
          {
            "value": "24",
            "label": "24"
          },
              {
            "value": "25",
            "label": "25"
          },
          {
            "value": "26",
            "label": "26"
          },
          {
            "value": "27",
            "label": "26"
          },
              {
            "value": "28",
            "label": "28"
          },
          {
            "value": "29",
            "label": "29"
          },
          {
            "value": "30",
            "label": "30"
          },
              {
            "value": "31",
            "label": "31"
          }
        ],
        "default": "1"
      },

      {
        "type": "select",
        "id": "start_time",
        "label": "Time",
        "options": [
          {
            "value": "00:00",
            "label": "12:00 AM"
          },
          {
            "value": "00:30",
            "label": "12:30 AM"
          },
          {
            "value": "01:00",
            "label": "1:00 AM"
          },
          {
            "value": "01:30",
            "label": "1:30 AM"
          },
              {
            "value": "02:00",
            "label": "2:00 AM"
          },
          {
            "value": "02:30",
            "label": "2:30 AM"
          },
          {
            "value": "03:00",
            "label": "3:00 AM"
          },
              {
            "value": "03:30",
            "label": "3:30 AM"
          },
          {
            "value": "04:00",
            "label": "4:00 AM"
          },
          {
            "value": "04:30",
            "label": "4:30 AM"
          },
              {
            "value": "05:00",
            "label": "5:00 AM"
          },
          {
            "value": "05:30",
            "label": "5:30 AM"
          },
          {
            "value": "06:00",
            "label": "6:00 AM"
          },
              {
            "value": "06:30",
            "label": "6:30 AM"
          },
          {
            "value": "07:00",
            "label": "7:00 AM"
          },
          {
            "value": "07:30",
            "label": "7:30 AM"
          },
              {
            "value": "08:00",
            "label": "8:00 AM"
          },
          {
            "value": "08:30",
            "label": "8:30 AM"
          },
          {
            "value": "09:00",
            "label": "9:00 AM"
          },
              {
            "value": "09:30",
            "label": "9:30 AM"
          },
          {
            "value": "10:00",
            "label": "10:00 AM"
          },
          {
            "value": "10:30",
            "label": "10:30 AM"
          },
              {
            "value": "11:00",
            "label": "11:00 AM"
          },
          {
            "value": "11:30",
            "label": "11:30 AM"
          },
          {
            "value": "12:00",
            "label": "12:00 PM"
          },
          {
            "value": "12:30",
            "label": "12:30 PM"
          },
          {
            "value": "13:00",
            "label": "1:00 PM"
          },
          {
            "value": "13:30",
            "label": "1:30 PM"
          },
              {
            "value": "14:00",
            "label": "2:00 PM"
          },
          {
            "value": "14:30",
            "label": "2:30 PM"
          },
          {
            "value": "15:00",
            "label": "3:00 PM"
          },
              {
            "value": "15:30",
            "label": "3:30 PM"
          },
          {
            "value": "16:00",
            "label": "4:00 PM"
          },
          {
            "value": "16:30",
            "label": "4:30 PM"
          },
              {
            "value": "17:00",
            "label": "5:00 PM"
          },
          {
            "value": "17:30",
            "label": "5:30 PM"
          },
          {
            "value": "18:00",
            "label": "6:00 PM"
          },
              {
            "value": "18:30",
            "label": "6:30 PM"
          },
          {
            "value": "19:00",
            "label": "7:00 PM"
          },
          {
            "value": "19:30",
            "label": "7:30 PM"
          },
              {
            "value": "20:00",
            "label": "8:00 PM"
          },
          {
            "value": "20:30",
            "label": "8:30 PM"
          },
          {
            "value": "21:00",
            "label": "9:00 PM"
          },
              {
            "value": "21:30",
            "label": "9:30 PM"
          },
          {
            "value": "22:00",
            "label": "10:00 PM"
          },
          {
            "value": "22:30",
            "label": "10:30 PM"
          },
              {
            "value": "23:00",
            "label": "11:00 PM"
          },
          {
            "value": "23:30",
            "label": "11:30 PM"
          }
        ],
        "default": "03:00"
      }
```

I did not know how to merge all the values together, but I came up with this and it seems to work, although redundant AF unless anyone knows a better way...

```
      {%- assign startDate = '' -%}
      {%- assign startDate = startDate | append: block.settings.start_year -%}
      {%- assign startDate = startDate | append: '-' -%}
      {%- assign startDate = startDate | append: block.settings.start_month -%}
      {%- assign startDate = startDate | append: '-' -%}
      {%- assign startDate = startDate | append: block.settings.start_day -%}
      {%- assign startDate = startDate | append: ' ' -%}
      {%- assign startDate = startDate | append: block.settings.start_time -%}
      {%- assign startDate = startDate | date: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' -%}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have search for date input settings but I haven't found any right solution so I tried my settings like this hope this help other's too.

a. click the link for scheme settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw7a4.png

b. then add this code to markup.

###### {% if block.settings.date  /
  {% if block.settings.month  /
   {{ block.settings.year }}

image link:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G1P7.png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

just wanted to give some update if someone is searching a Date Picker for the Product or Cart Page on Shopify.

There are a lot of apps ready in the Appstore like:
https://apps.shopify.com/date-picker

For me and the Team this was very easy to use and has saved us a lot of developer work.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question. (It shows the question may not be needed but it doesn't help someone who is looking for the answer).